# Make custom camera preview in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

i need help to make the following screen in xamarin forms , is there any body who can help me ?i tried to use custom render but i did not get any success. i don't know how to use popup on camera like this .any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epTPF.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to achive the result like following GIF?

[image]

If so, you can create a custom renderer view and use `Rg.Plugins.Popup` to achieve it.

And Use `RelativeLayout` to achieve pop button above CameraLayout.

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <RelativeLayout>

            <local:CameraPreview Camera="Rear" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
              RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                Type=RelativeToParent,
                Property=Width,
                Factor=1,
                Constant=0}"
             RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                Type=RelativeToParent,
                Property=Height,
                Factor=1,
                Constant=0}"
             />

            <Button Text="pop" Clicked="Button_Clicked"  BackgroundColor="Transparent"  
              RelativeLayout.XConstraint = "{ConstraintExpression 
                Type=RelativeToParent,
                Property=Width,
                Factor=1,
                Constant=-100}"
              RelativeLayout.YConstraint = "{ConstraintExpression 
                Type=RelativeToParent,
                Property=Height,
                Factor=1,
                Constant=-100}"
              RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                Type=RelativeToParent,
                Property=Width,
                Factor=.2,
                Constant=0}"
        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                Type=RelativeToParent,
                Property=Height,
                Factor=.1,
                Constant=0}"
                  />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

If you have some doubts about custom renderer view, you can refer to this ariticle.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view

Here is my demo link, you can download.

https://github.com/851265601/XFormsCameraPage

Comment: I can't believe there's not a single managed repository for a plugin to simply display a camera feed inside a view (not full screen). The only person who does is the one who manage zxing scannerview, but it is limited to reading barcodes.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT your repo is gone? or you made the repo private?